# how can i get the total size of all files contained (recursively for css file )in one html page?

Tags: java, html

all.

for the given page, say "http://www.yahoo.com", how can i calculate total size for the downloaded files, for example img files, javascript files, and css files?

I know the htmlparser jar, but this does not support  element for css file.

Comment: Do you need to use this information in say a JS? or is it just for your own information? Firebug for firefox can tell you this, as can the developer tools in chrome and IE. It also shows you load times over connections :)

Comment: this interface would be invoked by java in app to get overall info about some webpage.

Answer (score 1):

As Graeme mentioned, both the Firebug add-on for Firefox (a great tool for web developers btw) and the developer tools in Chrome will give you the info you want.

However if you dont want to download anything you can use this online service:

http://www.websiteoptimization.com/services/analyze/

And this will tell you how much is downloaded in bytes for a webpage, including images, style sheets, scripts and everything else.

Comment: how can I implement this function in Java myself?

Comment: if you dont fancy using an online utility to find total size for webpages, then all I can suggest is firebug (getfirebug.com). If you specifically need a Java applet which gets you this number I cant offer much more help sorry.